# Multiple Displays (physical monitor screens) in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, design-patterns, architecture

I'm developing a web app using React and Leaflet, and I want to have it display in 3 separate physical monitor screens where I have:

- the map in one screen mostly displaying ships on water
- reports, details and options in another one based on what ship is selected
- graphs in a third monitor.
  I'm not finding information online as to what the best way to achieve this is.

I'm thinking of even doing three separate apps, but not sure how good that is. Or if I just have the user run the app in 3 different browser tabs which will be dragged to their respective monitor, but I don't know if this is practical or even desirable to have 3 instances of the app running this way, and then how would they communicate?

You see I have several questions, and I believe this is something that requires help from a React architect or advanced programmer, not something you'd find on the docs, and there doesn't seem to exist examples like this.

I hope the question is clear enough and that you can shed some guidance. I'm using Node.js and MongoDB in the backend of things.

Comment: A web app or an Electron app? Comms between tabs is a separate issue from React and can be researched on its own (e.g., https://blog.bitsrc.io/4-ways-to-communicate-across-browser-tabs-in-realtime-e4f5f6cbedca); there are multiple solutions.

Comment: Web app. Thanks for the info about communication between tabs.

Comment: I would consider using one app and making your own breakpoints for a responsive design. Similar to how a site can be used on a phone, tablet and monitor. Then the user can stretch the window across 2,3 or even more monitors. Another option could be to make multiple, resizable columns with something like https://split.js.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create full screen functionality for each item, then open the same page on 3 separate monitors and on each monitor expand the item that interests you. regards